# Converting kilograms to grams in SQL query in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

In the following code there is a column name called `birthweight`, presently in the table where it is pulling form is displayed in 'kg', but I want it to be displayed in grams by converting kg to g

For example right now it shows 2.92 kg and I need to convert it to 2920.00 g

Comment: Hint:  `* 1000`.

Comment: i want it to be implemented in program and display exactly sir ,, kind of new to sql ..sorry it should show for example  2.92 kg should be displayed as 2920 g

Comment: So birthweight is a varchar column with mixed decimal and character data?

Comment: presently it is showing like this in the output                                                      
2.92 kg ;And i need it to be shown as                                                                                         2920.oo g

Comment: 2.92 * 1000 = 2920. Or when you say it is "showing 2.92 kg" do you mean you have "2.92 kg" in the table? Showing some sample data here would go a LONG way to this being answered.

Comment: Yes sean Lange  in the table it is displayed as 2.92 kg

Comment: PLEASE post sample data, not just stuff in the comments. It will make your question clear which currently it is not very clear. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @skumar - Check my answer and let us know if you are still facing problem.

Comment: Why would someone ever keep birthweight as kg??? Please correct that in the first place and store as grams. You might ignore my message and continue with working around by multiplying by 1000 or do a conversion from text (who would ever store it as text!) BUT my concern is you are dealing with medicine, hence lives (and worse with lives of babies). Just think  what your poorly designed might cause.

Comment: @skumar Whose smart idea to store data as `2.92 kg` (VARCHAR) instead of `2.92` (DECIMAL)???

Comment: @skumar, please ask a professional to revise your database and do the programming for you. Lives are not cheap to play with.

Comment: @skumar Also, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Poor babies in danger (birth weight has a great importance in calculating the medicine they would take, just make an error of an extra 0 and baby is gone).

Comment: @CetinBasoz perhaps this isn't a medical application and that level of precision is not required? Of course storing a number as formatted text is just horrible but we still don't really know if that is what the OP is doing because they seem to have disappeared.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_kg2gm] (@kg decimal(10,5))
RETURNS decimal(10,5)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (@kg * 1000)
END
To use this user-defined function (for example to convert 2.92 kg to gm):
SELECT dbo.ufn_kg2gm (2.92)

Comment: @SeanLange, if it is not a medical application then who would care about a birthweight? Storing number as text with its unit in the same column is an horrible matter, and being a medical application makes it scary.

Comment: @CetinBasoz There are plenty of other types of applications where you might store birthweight. Yes storing numbers as formatted text is horrific but there is no indication that people are making life and death decisions based on the information stored there.

Comment: @SeanLange when i used line by minimizing on etst program it worked fine but , when i paste that in my whole big program, it shows error again as Error converting data type varchar to float.   
ISnull(cast((cast(rtrim(replace(Visit.WeightField, 'kg', '')) as float) * 1000) as varchar(max)) + ' g' ,'') as Birthweight

Comment: That means you have some value in that table that doesn't match the pattern. Meaning at least one row has something other than "kg" in there. You really should try to fix the structure and store kilograms as an int.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this :

```
select cast((cast(rtrim(replace(birthweight, 'kg', '')) as float) * 1000) as varchar(50)) + ' g' birthweight from yourtable
```

Comment: I don't think it is quite this simple. I am pretty sure they have varchar data, not integer data.

Comment: @SeanLange - You are absolutely correct. I have updated the query.

Comment: hehe pretty much the same thing I posted. But I like yours a little better because it is a bit simpler. Well done!!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a Function to do this if you really wanted. I didn't totally test this out, but should give you an idea.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.converter (@kg decimal)  
RETURNS decimal  
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER  
AS  
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @g decimal
 SET @g = @kg * 1000

 RETURN(@g);  
END;
```

You would call it like such in your SELECT statement

```
SELECT CAST(dbo.converter([Your_KG_Column]) as decimal(18,2))
```

Comment: A scalar function is total overkill here, but I don't think they have the decimal datatype. Pretty sure it is formatted character data.

Comment: can anyone please help me modify the above program which i have given from my program.. to display the way i requested please

Comment: Yeah, it probably is overkill. I was just thinking if this is some sort of common requirement to do conversions, it could be expanded to do more and used elsewhere. But I agree in general for this single case if it's the only time it would be used...

Comment: But scalar functions are horrible for performance. So even if it was needed multiple times just do the math. :)

Comment: @skumar we can't help you because you haven't posted enough detail yet.

Comment: what  else do you want me to post

Comment: Sample data which has been asked multiple times. Read the link I posted.

Comment: @skumar I'm assuming you didn't like it because you were missing the .00 , see above you can use a CAST. I would read what Sean Lange said, performance is a issue. this code isn't production, just an idea to expand upon maybe.

Comment: @skumar - Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the real data might look like so I just tossed something together. Maybe this will help.

```
declare @Something table
(
    BirthWeight varchar(10)
)

insert @Something values
('2.92 kg')
, ('3.44 kg')
, ('1.89 kg')

select *
    , convert(varchar(10), convert(int, convert(decimal(7,2), replace(s.BirthWeight, ' kg', '')) * 1000)) + ' g'
from @Something s
```

Comment: USE masterdb
  DROP TABLE #PRG1
  SELECT DISTINCT

       ISNULL(Visit.WeightField,'') as 'Birthweight'

                  INTO #PRG1
                  FROM AbsAcct_RegData as Abs

                           INNER JOIN AbsAcct_VisitData as Visit
                           ON Abs.SourceID = Visit.SourceID
                           AND Abs.VisitID = Visit.VisitID

                           INNER JOIN RegAcct_Main as Reg
                           ON Abs.SourceID = Reg.SourceID
                           AND Abs.VisitID = Reg.VisitID

Comment: @skumar what is that supposed to show? If this is information about your question it should be in the question. But also realize that query is useless to anyone else because we don't have those tables.

Comment: Please don't do suggestions to workaround of storing text for birth weight.

Comment: @CetinBasoz what does your comment mean?

Comment: It means don't encourage OP to store birthweight (or any newborn weight) as text.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I didn't encourage it at all.

Comment: ,pr1 = isnull((select REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, EpisodeProcedureCode_MisAbsProcID ),'.','') from AbsAcct_EpisodeProcedures(nolock)
  where VisitID = HimVisit.VisitID and SortOrder=1),'')

Comment: using the above line is giving me error as Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I would guess that is because there is more than 1 row that is returned from the query. And do yourself a favor by not littering the nolock hint all over the place. It is far more sinister than most people realize. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/